# Customeformat is not working on my datetimepicker

Tags: winforms, date, datetime, c#-4.0, datetimepicker

i have facing a problem. A datetimepicker on my windows form and i set the format properties to Custom and CustomeFormat to `dd/MM/yyyy` but when i run the application the datetimepicker display the calendar `MM/dd/yyyy`. I want consistent format in my application that is `dd/MM/yyyy` . Below is the picture for better understanding.

[image: Format]

and Runtime datetimepicker displaying like below screen

[image]

Code that is generating in designer

```
 this.engageDateDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        this.engageDateDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Value", this.prol01BindingSource, "EngageDate", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, null, "d"));
        this.engageDateDateTimePicker.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.engageDateDateTimePicker.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        this.engageDateDateTimePicker.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(885, 96);
        this.engageDateDateTimePicker.Name = "engageDateDateTimePicker";
        this.engageDateDateTimePicker.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 20);
        this.engageDateDateTimePicker.TabIndex = 27;
        this.engageDateDateTimePicker.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.engageDateDateTimePicker_ValueChanged);
```

Can you tell me how can i resolve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you haven't set the [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format(v=vs.110).aspx) property appropriately on the picker. From the docs for `DateTimePicker.CustomFormat`:

> The `Format` property must be set to `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom` for this property to affect the formatting of the displayed date and time.

Comment: i have set the property that you can view in first image where i set the property . Is that i need to set the property by code.

Comment: @A.Goutam: No, in the first image you've shown setting the `CustomFormat` property. You haven't shown the `Format` property at all. You need to set both.

Comment: just i have replace first picture. Can you please take a look and plz give me your advice

Comment: @A.Goutam: Okay, that looks better. I'm now surprised. If you can put together a short but complete example (just creating a form manually in code - no designer involved) it would be easier to reproduce.

Comment: my code is for set format is like  ` engageDateDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;`  `this.engageDateDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";`

Comment: What Jon is saying is that those settings work for everyone else. If they're not working for you it's because you're doing something that you're not showing us and we can't guess what that is. Post code that lets us make the same issue occur otherwise it's unlikely we can help. This is not a bug in Winforms, it's something you're doing.

Comment: OK, it makes more sense now you've edited your post. What is the `prol01BindingSource` and where do you get it from? I'd guess this is the cause.